# data from arraylist is not added to tableModel

Tags: java

I made a GUI using `JTable(tableModel)` and a `JPanel` where the user can add data through `JTextFields` to an `Arraylist`, but for some reason when I click the add `JButton`, the adding fails and points to the line where I want to add the arraylist row to the tableModel.

```
public final static ArrayList<Members> adat = new ArrayList<>();

DefaultTableModel tableModel;
        String[][] dummy = new String[][]{{"001", "Jack Black", "London", "20"}};
        String[] header = new String[]{"id", "Name", "City", "Age"};
        tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(dummy, header);
        JTable t = new JTable();
        t.setModel(tableModel); 
        panel1.add(new JScrollPane(t));
        frame.add(panel1);

        JPanel jp = new EditPanel();
        frame.add(jp);
```

```
public static void newData() {                     // the "add" button function
         Members newMember = null;
            try {
                newMember = new Members(
                        Integer.parseInt(EditPanel.idEdit.getText()), 
                        EditPanel.nameEdit.getText(), 
                        EditPanel.cityEdit.getText(), 
                        Integer.parseInt(EditPanel.ageEdit.getText()) 
                );
                adat.add(newMember);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error in modification", ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            toTable();
        }
```

and the method `toTable()` gets the members data from the `arraylist` to the `JTable`

```
     static void toTable() {                 // adding the users data to the table 

        if (adat.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < adat.size(); i++) {
                int id = adat.get(i).id;
                String name = adat.get(i).name;
                String city = adat.get(i).city;
                int age = adat.get(i).age;

                Object[] data = new Object[4];

                data[0] = id;
                data[1] = name;
                data[2] = city;
                data[3] = age;                

                tableModel.addRow(data);   // this is the line where the error points

            }
        }        
    }
```

Comment: What's the exact error-message?

Answer (score 0):

You're encountering an error at `tableModel.addRow(data);` because `tableModel` does not have a method called `addRow` ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html)).
You probably mixed up the `DefaultTableModel tableModel` with the actual `JTable t`.
It should be `t.addRow(data)`, although you need to make `t` global first!

Comment: Thank you for answer! the problem was that i had to remove the `DefaultTableModel tableModel` row, because it made to see it as a new tableModel.